# Module not found error from imported package

Tags: python, import, setuptools

We are using an internally developed package `apv_core` that depends on the `ezdzx` package.  This packaged is build with `setup.py bdist_wheel` and then deployed to other applications in the solution.

When importing this package I get this error:

```
./.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apv_core/cad/dxf.py:3: in <module>
    import ezdxf
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ezdxf'
```

This suggests that the dependancy is not available in `apv_core`.  I rebuilt it ensuring the package is included.  All unit tests in `apv_core` that depends on `ezdxf` passes.  The `requirements.txt` is also correctly updated.

I can install `ezdxf` in the target application where `apv_core` is imported but this does not feel right.  My assumption is that all dependancies are included in the `wheel` that is built and deployed.  Is this not correct?

Comment: "*My assumption is that all dependancies are included in the wheel that is built and deployed. Is this not correct?*" Nope, dependencies are mentioned in wheels' metadata but not included. Pip installs dependencies by looking into the metadata but it installs them from separate wheels/sdists.

Comment: But that would mean that when I install `apv_core` it should include all the referenced packages.  i should not install them all from scratch?

Comment: Should install all from scratch. Every time. Not for upgrading but for every new installation.